# Dropbox iOS Core API: How to make sure DBRestClient deletedPath first before uploadFile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox core API to backup/upload core date sqllite file, users' images and a plist file. I don't want to keep versioning of the backup. I just want to keep the latest files whenever the user hits the backup button so I want to `[restClient deletePath:@"/myBackupFolder"]` first then upload all the files.

However, because delete and upload both run in the background synchronously, sometime the delete runs first, sometime the upload runs first. How do I make sure to run delete first then upload?

Also, the protocol

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
```

is called each time a file is uploaded successfully. I want to set an UIAlertView upon successful upload of all files. I don't want an alert upon each successful upload. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start the upload until the deletion is complete. In other words, start the upload when you get the call to:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client deletedPath:(NSString *)path;
```

For the uploads, you know how many files you need to upload. Keep track of how many calls to `restClient:uploadedFile:` are made. When the count reaches the proper total, you know that was the last upload. You can now show the alert.

Comment: I was hope there is a cleaner way to do what I wanted. I was able to do all I wanted using your Approach. Now I run into another problem with which I hope you could help.

I got the backup and restore working fine. However, after a restore which basically replaces all the backup files from dropbox with the local files (core data sqllite file, images and a plist), the core data does not show up after the restore. I have to either recompile the app or close the app from the dock then run it again for the core data to show up. How do i make core data show up immediately after the restore? Thanks

Comment: Dealing with core data after completely replacing the files is an entirely separate question requiring a completely different skill set. I suggest you search around a bit on the subject. If you can't find an answer, ask a new question specific to the core data issue.

Comment: I reset the persistentStoreCoordinator to load up the restored sqlite file, it worked.